# Nodejs Desktop app with electron starting server when app is launched

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am building my app with electron and nodejs together with express server.

What am trying to achieve is create a desktop app with angular2 handling the routing together with express

Now on my local developenment i have to start the server (express) so that i can  connect to the database, so i have the following that connects to the database

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
 password : 'your-password',
 database : 'cloudprint'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
 if(!err) {
   console.log("Database is connected ... nn");
} else {
   console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");
```

}
  });

THe above is run on a server.js which i start on the commandline through

```
npm server.js
```

Now am abit confused on how i can reuse the above in my app, since when a person installs the app he will not require to have to start server.js from commandline,

How should i approach this during production time.

Comment: you need to stop dev and learn electron before you paint yourself into a corner.

Comment: @dandavis does it mean my logic in using a frontend framework like angular2/4 is wrong or what..

Comment: you probably shouldn't have been running a manual node instance, unless that is meant to simulate a cloud service. electron provides you a node api for such tasks, and that's a really fundamental part of how it all works that you seem to have glossed over, or you wouldn't be asking the question above. cheers

Comment: @dandavis am trying to make sense of fetching data from electron using angular2. AM very familiar with angular2/4 and wanted to build an app which can fetch data from mysql locally. Previosuly i used angular2 to fetch data from a webservice but now its abit different i need to fetch data independently from the app without using a webservice. Could you have a reference of this, example how desktop apps work without a need for a webservice

Comment: i have already used electron before but the part which am unable to figure out is how to fetch data from mysql and present it to angular2 running with electron

Comment: come on buddy, this is Electron 101. read the manual (or even the intro) before attempting to use it. you might need to use some command-line-type node commands, but i'm pretty sure theres a sql npm package.

Comment: @dandavis could you please give an insight i am quite farmiliar with electron but the fetching data part without solely relying on nodejs starting the server is the main issue, i have used electron. Check on my previous coments to understand my issue \

Comment: https://github.com/garrylachman/ElectroCRUD